# What is the usual defintion of $K_1$ group?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, k-theory

On the book I am reading, $K_1$ group of a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ is defined to be

$K_1(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty} GL(M_n(A))/GL(M_n(A))_0=\lim_{n\to\infty} U(M_n(A))/U(M_n(A))_0$,

where $A_0$ is the path component containing $1$ and $U(A)$ is the unitary group of $A$.

This definition is very easy to understand for me, but I never read the same definition anywhere else. Are the definitions all the same?

Comment: This is the definition I'm used to.  Which other definition are you having trouble comparing this to?

Comment: @Ruy well I have seen several different definitions such as that on wiki pedia. I just don't know which is the original one. Some terms have a lot of different definitions don't they?

Comment: Could you please tell me which Wikipedia page you are referring to?  There is one on Topological and another on Algebraic K-Theory.

Comment: @Ruy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_K-theory